# .load function went wrong if there is anchor (#) in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My page have some parts that will be populated by .load()

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
 if (document.getElementById('add_to_userlist')) {
  $('#add_to_userlist').load(script_name + '?' + nv_name_variable + '=' + nv_module_name + '&' + nv_fc_variable + '=v_funcs&mod_list=user_playlist' + '&id={DETAIL.id}' + '&fcheck={DETAIL.check_session}' + '&nocache=' + new Date().getTime());
 }
 if (document.getElementById('favourite-{DETAIL.id}')) {
  $('#favourite-{DETAIL.id}').load(script_name + '?' + nv_name_variable + '=' + nv_module_name + '&' + nv_fc_variable + '=v_funcs&mod_list=get_fav' + '&id={DETAIL.id}' + '&fcheck={DETAIL.check_session}' + '&nocache=' + new Date().getTime());
 }
 $(".bodytext_shorten").shorten({showChars: 200});
});
```

Everything is okay but if there is an anchor in this URL, like :

> http://nukeviet-hvt.rhcloud.com/videos/chuyen-muc-1/sau-tim-thiep-hong-giao-linh-ft-tuan-vu-2.html#comment_box

The page does not load as it should. The div with id id `#add_to_userlist` and `favourite-{DETAIL.id}` load entire of page instead of a HTML part only.
So the page keep reload and enable my flood blocker.

I think there is a conflict but don't know how to solve it.

Google Chrome show this in Console

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: You get any errors within your console?

Comment: Yes, please check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `load` method doesn't support fragment identifiers in URLs to determine which part of a document to load.

The syntax it supports is a space followed by a CSS selector.

```
.load("http://nukeviet-hvt.rhcloud.com/videos/chuyen-muc-1/sau-tim-thiep-hong-giao-linh-ft-tuan-vu-2.html #comment_box")
```

---

It isn't entirely clear from the question, but it looks like you have that value in `script_name` and then are trying to add the query string after it.

In a URL the query string must appear **before** the fragment identifier.

In `load()` syntax, the selector must appear after the entire URL (i.e. after the query string and after any fragment identifier).

Comment: Thank you but `#comment_box`  in this URL is only a anchor tag, and Browser will scroll to this id. Function .load select `#add_to_userlist` id.

Comment: @KennyNguyen — Then you'll have to write a different selector that matches the element you care about.